# Multicore processing on a linux with R

Tags: r, linux, parallel-processing, multicore

I am trying to perform a Hardy Weinberg Exact test using the procedure implicated by the R package pegas. The code I have written applied the test with 10^5 permutations to each of 54 populations, and then writes the p-value results to a sincle matrix. I am using a for-loop to apply the process automatically to all 54 pops one at at a time using the following code.

```
for(M in 1:nPop(cod))
{
hw.result <- hw.test(cod[pop=M], B = 100000)# Carry out hw test on pop M
HWE.matrix[,M] <- hw.result[,"Pr.exact"]# Feed results into the matrix
}
```

I have tested the code with low permuations and all runs smoothly, but of course with 10^5 its a bit much for my 4GIG processor. I am trying to use it on a linux machine with 8*4gig processors but am struggling with how to instruct R to make use of all of the processors. I have modified the code for parallel processing based on reading several instructional [blogs](https://beckmw.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/a-brief-foray-into-parallel-processing-with-r/) so that it looks like this

```
 foreach(i in 1:nPop(cod)) %dopar%
{
hw.result <- hw.test(cod[pop=i], B = 100000)# Carry out hw test on pop M
HWE.matrix[,i] <- hw.result[,"Pr.exact"]# Feed results into the matrix
}
```

and am getting the error: doSnowGlobals not found, I have googled the error and am not finding anything that seems to apply. I am a relative novice at R and completely new to parallel processing, but have been on this for days, so it would be nice to have someone help me to work through this.

Comment: Have you read the vignette for package 'parallel' which came with your installation of R?

Comment: I have done yes, hence having a grasp on making the clusters. I don't understand it in it's entirety, and am having trouble identifying which parts are relevant to me. I have experimented with a few parts but to no avail.